# Clear memory after some number of records passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection, sidekiq

I have few m of records in db, and need to process it from time to time. However this operation takes all memory on my server. I'm running this operation using sidekiq. So while this task using all memory, my rails app becomes very slow.

In general(no logic included) my code looks like

```
Model.each do |m|
//do some logic code here
end
```

How do i make garbage collector to run after some amount of records(for ex. 10k records) so i wouldn't face out of memory situations. Will splitting it in chunks help me?

Comment: It almost sounds like you have some kind of recursion going on if the information is staying in the stack...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always use [find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) when dealing with potentially large tables.

That way, models will be retrieved from the database and loaded in memory batch by batch (the default size is 1000 but you can customize it to your needs).

Just be aware that sorting by arbitrary columns doesn't play well with `find_each`, as it implicitly sorts records by ID so that it has a way to fetch records by batches.

Answer (score 4):

You can force the garbage collector to run with `GC.start`, but if you are doing

```
Model.all.each do |m|
end
```

then garbage collection cannot free the already processed records - they are still referenced by the array that `each` is iterating over, so running the garbage collector explicitly won't do anything.

Instead use `find_each` (or its close relative, `find_in_batches`) which fetches records and processes them in batches (you can control the batch size - I think it is 1000 by default). This way the entire result set is never in memory and previously processed batches are not referenced by anything and so can be disposed of.